# Connect pairs of points in ListPlot by arrows

Tags: plotting

A have set of parameters (p1, p2, p3, l, ...) taken at different time. I would like to plot them connecting the same param. with arrows from older point to the recent ones so I could see evolution of params in time. Could you help please. No idea how to do it :(

```
mydata = {
 {"p1", "2015-11-26", 5, 6},
 {"p3", "2015-05-30", 15, 5},
 {"p1", "2014-01-17", 9, 16},
 {"p2", "2015-11-26", 5, 6},
 {"p2", "2013-06-03", 0, 1},
 {"l4", "2015-01-07", 17, 5},
 {"p3", "2015-01-07", 9, 12},
 {"p3", "2015-03-07", 24, 13},
 {"p3", "2015-06-07", 19, 16}

 }

ListPlot[Partition[mydata[[All, 3 ;; 4]], Length[mydata]][[1]], 
PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[(SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ GatherBy[mydata, First])[[All, All, 3 ;; 4]], 
 PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates[mydata[[All, 1]]],BaseStyle -> Thick] /. 
  Line -> Arrow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How can I style arrows in this solution?

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков, you can use `Arrowheads` with `PlotStyle`; for example,  `PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[.075]]`.